# MSBuild and IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to write a MSBuild project that will generate html documentation using doxygen. I couldn't find anything about that on the net except for one [example](https://salamanca.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/src/misc/Salamanca.Project.msbuild), which seems incomplete; it doesn't parse doxygen warnings.

I found that [MSBuild's Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task has parameters like IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat and CustomWarningRegularExpression. What is the "Standard Error/Warning Format" and what kind of REs are allowed in these properties?

Edit: ah, "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine" wrongly describes it as property in .NET 3.5, where it is actually from 4. No use for me...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard msbuild error/warning format is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111201011931/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx).

In a nutshell, the format is:

> MSBuild recognizes error messages and warnings that have been specially formatted by many command line tools that typically write to the console. For instance, take a look at the following error messages - they are all properly formatted to be MSBuild and Visual Studio friendly.
>
> ```
> Main.cs(17,20): warning CS0168: The variable 'foo' is declared but never used 
> C:\dir1\foo.resx(2) : error BC30188: Declaration expected.
> cl : Command line warning D4024 : unrecognized source file type 'foo.cs', object file assumed
> error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.dll' could not be found.
> ```
>
> These messages confirm to special format that is shown below, and comprise 5 parts - the order of these parts are important and should not change:
>
> [image: Canonical Errors/Warnings]
>
> *Origin (Required)*
>
> Origin can be blank. If present, the origin is usually a tool name, like 'cl' in one of the examples. But it could also be a file name, like 'Main.cs' shown in another example. If it is a file name, then it must be an absolute or a relative file name, followed by an optional parenthesized line/column information in one of the following forms:
>
> ```
> (line) or (line-line) or (line-col) or (line,col-col) or (line,col,line,col)
> ```
>
> *Subcategory (Optional)*
>
> Subcategory is used to classify the category itself further, and should not be localized.
>
> *Category (Required)*
>
> Category must be either 'error' or 'warning'. Case does not matter. Like origin, category must not be localized.
>
> *Code (Required)*
>
> Code identifies an application specific error code / warning code. Code must not be localized and it must not contain spaces.
>
> *Text (Optional)*
>
> User friendly text that explains the error, and *must* be localized if you cater to multiple locales.

Answer (score 6):

The format is fully documented in the MSBuild source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Shared/CanonicalError.cs).

Comment: Ah, the perils of open-sourcing software. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I can't find docs on it right now, but I think the standard error format is something like

```
.*(\d+(,\d+(,\d+,\d+)?)?)?: error .*:.*
.*(\d+(,\d+(,\d+,\d+)?)?)?: warning .*:.*
```

examples:

```
c:\somefile.txt(10,20,10,30): error CMD1234: blarg
c:\somefile.txt(10,20): error CMD1234: yadda yadda
c:\somefile.txt: warning ARG5678: blah blah
```

Comment: I couldn't find it either. Anyone?