# I want to redirect output from our code review tool that we run in VS2010, so that we can click on output to goto file, line, column

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I want to redirect output from our code review tool that we are writing in VS2010, so that it's messages are parsed by Vs2010 and we can click on them to goto file, line, column.

I vaguely remember learing about this in vs2005, you output your text to a certain kind of window, with the exact format below, and then vs would parse the message and you could click on it to goto the specific location...

D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp_Test_BLL\Evaluation\Reports\TestEvaluationHistoryBLL.cs(27,44): warning CS0649: Error text

It was constructed thusly :

full file path:[error or warning type]:error message

Then it just worked "magically"..

But this is all I can remember from a conversation ~10 years ago about how to do this.
Does anyone remember what I'm talking about and can direct me to information about how to make this work with output from a tool we write to work within visual studio 2010?

Maybe a tutorial?

This post:
[Formatting the output of a custom tool so I can double click an error in Visual Studio and the file opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419415/formatting-the-output-of-a-custom-tool-so-i-can-double-click-an-error-in-visual)

Talks about doing it in the build, but I'd like to be able to run the code review tool independantly and get it to work too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it right in your question.

As an example, create a file in your temp directory (in a command prompt do `echo %temp%` to find it) called `test.bat`

Add the following to `test.bat`:

```
@echo D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp_Test_BLL\Evaluation\Reports\TestEvaluationHistoryBLL.cs(27,44): warning CS0649: Error text
```

Now in VS10, select `Tools`->`External Tools...`.  In the new window, select `Add`.

In the `Command:` field, enter `%temp%\test.bat`

Select `Use Output window` and click `OK`.

Your new tool should now show up in VS10's `Tools` menu.  If you click on it, your Output window should display a clickable message, which will open "D:\Project Files\CIS3G\Webapp_Test_BLL\Evaluation\Reports\TestEvaluationHistoryBLL.cs" if it exists, and will put the cursor on line 27 if it exists (if not, line 1) at column 44 if it exists (if not, column 1).

You can go further and add a shortcut key to your custom tool.

Select `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Keyboard`.  Find your tool in the list of commands.  It will show as `Tools.ExternalCommand[x]` where `[x]` is its position in the list of External Tools.  Enter your chosen shortcut key(s) in the `Press shortcut keys:` box and click `OK`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on doing this written in 2004 that still applies today:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6176/Using-the-Output-Window-in-DevStudio

Yes, I wrote it, but as was pointed out earlier, there is nothing particularly magic about this. The article mentions VC6 and VC7, but I still use this technique in VS2005, VS2008, and VS2010 for the output of PC-Lint.

Comment: Marking the other as the answer as it was slightly more helpful in vs2010 but this is good stuff thanks!